# Magento, product images not loading in both backend and frontend

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, magento

I have searched high and low for 2 days now and I saw that many have had a similar problem, but nothing worked for me yet and no problem was exactly like mine. So I hope someone has a good idea.

My problem: I can't see any product images wether in frontend nor in backend.

What I've tried so far:

- I did reinstall and drop database 5 times
- I'm using `version 1.9.3` (started out with `1.9.2.4`, no difference)
- I'm using `PHP 5.6`
- I checked if the images uploaded to the server, they did and the path matches when I check through the browser.
- I cleared all caches and re-indexed a million times.
- I tried to rename `.htaccess` to `.htaccess-old` (Just to check whether it would change or not)
- I checked with my hosting and they do run `GD2 Library`.
- the PHP limit is `520m`
- No extensions are installed
- I can see other images, like the logo

If you need any info please ask.
I hope that someone is able to help. Thank you!!

Comment: can you provide me a url.

Comment: http://falconfood.dk/new/index.php/test/iceberg.html I only made one test product, but this is the one.
On my first installation i made 300 products and it was the same.

Comment: check this error http://falconfood.dk/new/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/75x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/papir_kvalitet.jpg

Comment: Thank you. I only just enables the error log, and dont find any errors. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you check media folder and media/catalog folder's permission?

Comment: Yes Kul, the mediafolder and subfolders are all 777.

Comment: @faizanbeg The images are placed at the link location in FTP. Something is blocking them from showing, hence the error.

Comment: http://falconfood.dk/new/index.php/

Comment: have you checked your .htaccess

Comment: Hi Faizanbeg, what should I check for? I tried to rename it (suggested by my hosting provider), but it didn't change anything.